# Make binary Pairing array from dynamic associative array on the basis of Keys, One Element from each Key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm Basically Creating Pair from a dynamic associative array in such a manner that I took 1 element from one key array and other element from other key array on which these two elements combine make pair 1. Problem is this a dynamic associative array it can have 4 Keys having arrays every key can have maximum two elements and minimum 1 elememt in its array and to make pair we should have two keys having 1 element on both side of these two keys array.
For Example

```
    [parent_id] => Array
            (
                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 11
                        [1] => 12
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 13
                        [1] => 14
                    )

                [20] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 21
                        [1] => 22
                    )
                [21] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 23
                    )

            )
```

This is an associative array which gives 3 pairs right now.
For Example 

**pair 1** contain: 11 , 13
**pair 2** contain: 12 , 14
 
**pair 3** contain: 21 , 23

Now the Issue is by using what methodology I can get my desire result.
Any Suggestions !!!!

Comment: How do you decide to pair the values from element 9 with element 10 and not element 20 or 21?

Comment: I just give an Example but the pairing depends on 1 element from 1 key and second element from other key it doesn't matter you take it from 20 , 21 or 10

Comment: and that is where i stuck :P

Comment: So it would also be a valid result to get 11, 21; 12,22; and 13, 23?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Can you give me any suggestion @Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 3**

The last update didn't find all the possible pairs for one case. This version loops through differently, taking at most one element from each array before moving to the next one and pairing from there. It loops until there are insufficient values left to pair.

```
function find_pairs($array) {
    // re-index to 0
    $array = array_values($array['parent_id']);
    // sort so the longest arrays are first
    usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });
    // output array
    $pairs = array();
    $c = count($array);
    $i = 0;
    // loop while there are enough values to pair (2 or more)
    while (array_reduce($array, function ($c, $v) { return $c + count($v); }, 0) > 1) {
        // make sure there are some elements in this array
        while (!count($array[$i])) $i = ($i + 1) % $c;
        // find the next array with a value
        $j = ($i + 1) % $c;
        while (!count($array[$j])) $j = ($j + 1) % $c;
        // have we come full circle?
        if ($j == $i) break;
        // save the pair
        $pairs[] = array(array_shift($array[$i]), array_shift($array[$j]));
        // move on to the next array
        $i = ($i + 1) % $c;
    }
    return $pairs;
}
```

[Demo (includes all possible test cases) on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kK4Zo)

**Original answer**

Here's one way to do this. Re-index the `parent_id` array to start at 0, and then loop through the array 2 elements at a time, combining all the values from each element. We use `min` to make sure we only pair as many values as there are in the smallest value array.

```
// re-index to 0
$array = array_values($array['parent_id']);
// output array
$pairs = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 1; $i += 2) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < min(count($array[$i]), count($array[$i+1])); $j++) {
        $pairs[] = array($array[$i][$j], $array[$i+1][$j]);
    }
}
print_r($pairs);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 13 )
  [1] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 14 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [0] => 21 [1] => 23 ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ps2pG)

**Update**

If you want to guarantee getting the maximum number of pairs from the array, sort to make the longest arrays come first:

```
$array = array_values($array['parent_id']);
// sort so the longest arrays are first
usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });
// output array
$pairs = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 1; $i += 2) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < min(count($array[$i]), count($array[$i+1])); $j++) {
        $pairs[] = array($array[$i][$j], $array[$i+1][$j]);
    }
}
print_r($pairs);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UZueA)

**Update 2**

Based on further comments, it seems the only requirement for pairing is that the key of the array from which the elements from is not the same. This makes things a bit more complicated, but this function should do what you want:

```
function find_pairs($array) {
    // re-index to 0
    $array = array_values($array['parent_id']);
    // sort so the longest arrays are first
    usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });
    // output array
    $pairs = array();
    for ($i = 0, $j = 1; $i < count($array) - 1; $i++) {
        if (!count($array[$i])) continue;
        while ($j <= $i || $j < count($array) && !count($array[$j])) $j++;
        while (count($array[$i]) && isset($array[$j]) && count($array[$j])) {
            $pairs[] = array(array_shift($array[$i]), array_shift($array[$j]));
            // exhausted other arrays elements?
            while ($j < count($array) && !count($array[$j])) $j++;
        }
    }
    return $pairs;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/dcKnX)

Comment: You Saved My half Day Man (:

Comment: This is not giving me the right output as you see [Check this](https://3v4l.org/LQXkV)

Comment: @NaveedCheema what result do you expect from that? 12,25 is valid according to your previous comments.

Comment: It  contains  two pairs but giving us 1 12,25; other pair would be  22,23 or 22,24

Comment: @NaveedCheema would you be happy with 25,23 and 22,24?

Comment: @NaveedCheema see my edit. That will give you the maximum number of pairs from any set of data, as long as you don't mind the ordering.

Comment: I'm not saying this, what i'm trying two say we have to make pairs every possible condition , if it contain two pairs than we should give two pairs. that is what I'm trying to acheive

Comment: Ok look at this [example](https://3v4l.org/qhcPJ) as this wil give us two pairs but it is giving one pair 23 , 12; 24  , 22 can also make one pair. It is not depending on the inner keys(0 , 1) .

Comment: @NaveedCheema this is more complicated than your original question. Let me think about it some more.

Comment: No problem I'm also Seeing Your Soluton as I like the way. And I'll let you know if I did it first (: by help of yours

Comment: @NaveedCheema I've added a new solution which will work for all possible test cases (and a demo for all of them). This has been a good puzzle!